# How can you create a simple dialog box in Dynamics AX?

Tags: x++, axapta

How can you create a simple dialog box in Dynamics ax?

Comment: you should accept your answer: it's a good, working solution.

Answer (score 25):

```
static void DialogSampleCode(Args _args)
{
    Dialog      dialog;
    DialogField field;
    ;
    dialog = new Dialog("My Dialog");
    dialog.addText("Select your favorite customer:");
    field = dialog.addField(typeid(CustAccount));

    dialog.run();
    if (dialog.closedOk())
    {
        info(field.value());
    }
}
```

Comment: `field = dialog.addField(extendedTypeStr(CustAccount)); //AX 2012`

Answer (score 23):

for really simple dialog boxes, use the [Box Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa590624.aspx):

```
    Box::info("your message");
```

or

```
    Box::warning("your message");
```

or

```
    if (Box::okCancel("continue?", DialogButton::Cancel) == DialogButton::Ok)
    {
        // pressed OK
        ...
```

or one of the other static methods (`infoOnce`, `yesNo`, `yesNoCancel`, `yesAllNoAllCancel`, ...)

Answer (score 0):

DAX 2012 does not have "typeid" as a method. But you can use extendedTypeStr and then pass in either a known EDT or use the built in string length versions:

```
str getStringFromUser(str _prompt, str _title)
{
    str         userResponse = "";
    Dialog      dlg = new Dialog(_title);
    DialogField dlgUserResponse = dlg.addField(extendedTypeStr(String15), _prompt);

    // This prompts the dialog
    if (dlg.run())
    {
        try
        {
            userResponse = dlgUserResponse.value();
        }
        catch(Exception::Error)
        {
            error("An error occurred. Please try again.");
        }
    }
    return userResponse;
}
```