# Yes/No Box Class

Tags: axapta, x++

I'm trying to create a yes/no Box to appear in Microsoft Dynamics AX.

When yes is clicked, the process proceeds and when no is selected the process is cancelled. What would the code be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you create a simple dialog box in Dynamics AX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379714/how-can-you-create-a-simple-dialog-box-in-dynamics-ax)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (Box::yesNo("Do you want to continue?", DialogButton::No) == DialogButton::Yes)
{
    info("We have clicked yes");
}
else
{
    info("We have clicked no");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a box is not the correct way to go.

Take a look on the [RunBase Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa863262.aspx), you will find hundreds of examples on its use in the standard code base.

The dialog is handled in `dialog` method and will default to an OK/Cancel dialog, if not provided. The `run` method contains the processing.